# Wygwam Upgrade to v3.0.2

Tags: wygwam, upgrade, editor

After performing a upgrade from Wygwam 2.7.1 to Wygwam 3.0.2 the wygwam-field doesn't appear anymore. For a brief moment it shows the html-code inside the field, but when the editor should appear nothing happends.

Tried it in IE en Firefox, cleared cache.

Does anyone know where to look?

With kind regards,

Jeroen van Dijk

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened and was a cache problem -- I cleared the cache; it started working again. I know you said you tried that, but give it another go.

Comment: Hmmmm, cleared the IE cache again, and cleared the Cache of EE (can't imagine that does the trick, but you never know) and voila problem solved :-)

Comment: Can I ask you to vote this answer correct, then ? :)